# Strange NullPointer from unknown source

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-api-client

I have a very frustrating null pointer that comes up when I launch my application. It did not start until I updated Android Studio and Google Play Services. I switched from using LocationClient to using GoogleApiClient. Then my app crashes unexpectedly out of nowhere when I try to launch it. I have been trying to fix this for about a week and I cannot guess where this problem is coming from. This is the log when the crash happens

```
Process: com.android.wallfly, PID: 3941
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nj$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of reasons for the app crash and getting a Null pointer, If you are very sure its not the code may be you can try to install/upgrade the Google Play Services to the latest version from SDK manager. GoogleApClient is the hook provided throughout the API's make sure you have latest version of the Google Play Services and also select the type of app (mobile, wearable etc) and reimport Google Play Services and add as a Lib in your app.
Hope this would help!!

Comment: If build project does not throw any errors, his library is fine, maybe he is missing latest google repository.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Should I delete my version of Google Play Services and re add the library in the current version of Android Studio?